# Is a python virtual environment entirely self-contained?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

If I copy a python virtual environment and then set the VIRTUAL_ENV variable inactivate.bat file to the correct directory, is that environment entirely self-contained?  In particular, if I were to copy this venv to a machine that has no other version of python on it, set the environment, and then activate, should I be able to run python programs or will there be missing files?

(If the situation were different, I could just get an extra machine at work and experiment with this, but things are a little hectic and I would like to have some idea that this works before I jump through hoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A `venv` virtual environment does not contain the python interpreter, among other things.

```sh
$ ls -l venv/bin/python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  staff  24 Oct 19 21:07 venv/bin/python3.8 -> /usr/local/bin/python3.8
```